# How can I pass value to Perl Subroutine parameters on command line?

Tags: perl, parameters, subroutine

my ***test.pl*** script as below.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;


sub printargs
{
    print "@_\n";
}

&printargs("hello", "world"); # Example prints "hello world"
```

If I replaced `printargs("hello", "world");` with `print($a, $b);`.

How to pass 'hello' ,'world' to $a , $b when I run ***perl test.pl hello world*** at command line, Thanks.

Comment: You would be wise to omit the `&` from `&printargs(...)`.  You don't need it and prefixing sub calls with `&` can have side-effects which you probably aren't expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ARGV[0] contains the first argument, $ARGV[1] contains the second argument, etc.

$#ARGV is the subscript of the last element of the @ARGV array, so the number of arguments on the command line is $#ARGV + 1.

Comment: You can also just use @ARGV to get the number of elements.
eg: if (@ARGV < 2) { die "Usage: " . $0 . " <param>\n"; }

Answer (score 4):

Do read about [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 3):

The command-line arguments are in the `@ARGV` array.  Just pass that to your function:

```
&print( @ARGV );
```

Probably best to avoid a name like `print` - might get confused with the built-in function of the same name.

Comment: Thank you. Revised *print* to *printargs*

Answer (score 1):

You want to access "command line parameters" in Perl.

Basically Perl sees the string you pass after the actual script name as an array named @ARGV.

Here is a brief tutorial: http://devdaily.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00001.shtml

Just google "perl command line parameters" for more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as others said, the @ARGV list is the answer to your question.

Now if you want to go further and define command lines options for your programs, you should also have a loog at [getargs.](http://search.cpan.org/~dcoppit/Getargs-Long-1.1003/lib/Getargs/Long.pm)

Answer (score 0):

This would also print "hello world" from the command line arguments while passing the data to $a and $b as requested.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

sub printargs($$)
{
    print $_[0] . " " . $_[1] . "\n";
}

my($a,$b) = ($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1]);
printargs($a,$b);
```